# Why is the socket voltage in Mexico 127V?

Tags: voltage, power-grid

As per the title, this is a very specific figure. Is there a reason it's 127 instead of 120V or 130V?

Comment: Is there a reason you find the numbers 120 and 130 more natural except that they're easily expressed in "numbers of fingers I have on my hands"? This is not meant to be flippant, but if you ask "why not X", I expect a reason for expecting X.

Comment: @DonFusili, well yes, partially. Our entire counting system is base 10 simply because we have 10 fingers. That's why we refer to numbers that are multiples of 10 as "round numbers". Not only that, but a supplied voltage is always going to be +/- 5-10V around the nominal supply so again, 127V is very specific when compared to a "round number" of 120 or 130.

Comment: Don was providing a Socratic question... Anyways Saudi Arabia also has 127 volts as well. The reasons is just for convention. This question has the same answer on why we Americans have 120 volts instead of 127 volts or why the majority of Europe has 220 to 240 volts. The reason for our differences most likely has to do with the machines we make in our specific country that generate a specific voltage.

Comment: Sure, but electricity generation is mainly based on which one of the N working ones that is stable and mature enough a country decided to copy. I'd have understood this question better if your reasoning was "I'd expect it to be the same as the US in case they need to transfer power across the border". I don't see why someone would care about having a round number just for having a round number's sake.

Comment: Also, as an aside, I prefer that the people that have control over my electric supply don't have more problems with an interval centered on 127 than one centered on 120.

Comment: @DonFusili OK, back to basics; what dictates the voltage *any* country uses? Is it just arbitrary? I don't know. However, I'm aware of 220V and 110V - both round numbers because, I assume, the actual voltage is rarely exactly those values. I.e. accurate to two significant figures. The Mexico (and others) voltage is accurate to three S.F.s so are they more confident of the accuracy of their supply voltage?

Comment: @Darren It's not just arbitrary, it's used to be efficient during transportation. Regarding the S.F.: We've gotten pretty good at keeping voltages stable, good enough that when the system fails, we get news bulletins that tell us our clocks aren't ticking correctly. Both are already answered at other places on this SE, though :-)

Comment: Why the voltages: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/204068/175537

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Saw this on another site  https://www.electronicspoint.com/threads/127-volt-standard-voltage.164594/

> Much, maybe all, of Mexico supplies single phase power via 2 phases from
>   three phase power. In the US that is known in the power industry as
>   "network power" and is usually 120/208 volts. Now 208 volts sucks. But
>   to get 240 volts from such a configuration, you'd have to have 138.5 volts
>   on line to neutral, and that is a bit too much for most things that want
>   120 volts. In Mexico they have chosen a compromise where the L-N voltage
>   is just a little high (127 volts) and the L-L voltage is just a little low
>   (220 volts).

Sounds reasonable. Haven't been able to find any search terms that yield anything better.

Comment: Thank you very much for actually giving a reason instead of a facetious “why not?”. +1 and I will accept this as an answer in a day or two if no better answers come along.

Answer (score 4):

Mexico provides two phases of a 3-phase system at the residential level that are 120 degrees of phase apart, in contrast to US 180 degree split-phase.

So in the US the 120-0-120 L1-N-L2 system provides 120 line to neutral and 240 line to line. In Mexico they get 220 line to line and 127 line to neutral. It's a 127/220 3-phase system whereas US 3-phase systems are 120/208.  The ratio of the higher number to the lower number is root(3)

Answer (score 3):

The Mexican electrical grid is an unstable grid. It is not well maintained and is subject to highs and low of a frequent nature. 127 volts allows for the electrical distributor (CFE) to have greater flexibility in the power delivery. The 127 standard is slightly higher than the 120 standard for the bulk of the rest of North America but allows for variance of as much as 10% and still be within the confines of what is acceptable. For example: if the grid was set to 120 volts and an increase or decrease occurred of 10% (generally acceptable margin of error for power delivery on a single phase line) the allowance would only be to 132 volts or the low of 108. With 127 volt the variance is slightly more substantial - with an acceptable high of about 138 volt and a low of about 114. Generally the delivery system has a tendency to deliver over-voltage as opposed to under voltage and this 127 standard allows for a greater over voltage delivery with less concern of being outside acceptable parameters. In other words, it takes less work and energy to maintain a 127 volt grid than it does to maintain a 120 volt grid.